# How to compute $ \prod_0^n( 1- { 2 \over (2+k)(3+k)}= $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have spent quite some time to solve this question, before I asked Wolfram Alpha and got this:

$$ \prod_0^n \left(1- {2\over(2+k)(3+k)}\right)  = { n+4 \over 3(n+2)}. $$

Now that I know that this is probably right I can proof it via induction. 
However I would like to know, how you could come to that conclusion by hand / without the help of Wolfram Alpha.

Answer (score 5):

$$1-\frac{2}{(2+k)(3+k)}=\frac{k^2+5k+4}{k^2+5k+6}=\frac{(k+1)(k+4)}{(k+2)(k+3)}$$
If you write the terms out with those factors, you will find a lot of cancellation.

Comment: wow, that was quick, thank you, I didn't try to factorize the terms. In fact I forgot how powerful that actually can be. Thank you again.